# IBM i C++ Open a printer file using std::ofstream

Tags: c++, ibm-midrange

EDIT:  This question is for the [IBM i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_i) operating system.  IBM i is a unique operating system that runs on IBM POWER servers and was formerly called OS/400.  Current release is 7.5.  In IBM i, printer files are a subclass of *FILE-type objects that provide a templated interface to programs by which they can create spool files on output queues.  I am trying to understand from someone specifically knowledgeable about the platform if they can be opened using fstream classes in ILE.

Can anyone help me understand how to open a printer file in ILE C++ using an ofstream or if it is not possible? I've tried each of the following without success:

```
std::ofstream stream("QSYSPRT");    // Makes a new text file named QSYSPRT in /home/<user>
std::ofstream stream("QSYSPRT   *LIBL     ");    // Makes a new text file named "QSYSPRT   *LIBL     " in /home/<user>
std::ofstream stream("*LIBL/QSYSPRT");    // Open fails
std::ofstream stream("/QSYS.LIB/QSYSPRT.FILE");    // Open fails
std::ofstream stream("/QSYS.LIB/QSYSPRT.FILE/QSYSPRT.MBR");    // Open fails
```

Comment: Which platform?  What OS?  Usually, printer communication is handled by the operating system.  Are you using a GUI framework?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Platform and OS is in the title and tags:  IBM i/ibm-midrange.  OS formerly known as OS/400, platform colloquially called AS/400 but runs on IBM POWER servers now.

Comment: Are you using the ILE C++ compiler?  Or something in PASE?

Comment: @Charles The program is an ILE program so the ILE C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Printer files are normally record oriented, just like data base table on the IBM i.

I wouldn't expect ofstream to work with them.

The [ILE C/C++ Programmer's Guide](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=files-record-functions-printer) says:

> Use the following record functions to process printer files:
>
> - _Rclose()
> - _Rfeod()
> - _Rformat()
> - _Rindara()
> - _Riofbk()
> - _Ropen()
> - _Ropnfbk()
> - _Rupfb()
> - _Rwrite()

Now QSYSPRT is a special animal

```
                            Display File Field Description                          
Input parameters                                                                    
  File  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :  QSYSPRT                            
    Library . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :  *LIBL                              
File Information                                                                    
  File  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :  QSYSPRT                            
    Library . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :  QSYS                               
  Number of record formats  . . . . . . . . . :      1                              
  Type of file  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :  Device                             
  File creation date  . . . . . . . . . . . . :  12/03/18                           
  Text 'description'. . . . . . . . . . . . . :  System non-described printer file  
Record Format Information                                                           
  Record format . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :  QSYSPRT                            
  Format level identifier . . . . . . . . . . :  0000000000000                      
  Number of fields  . . . . . . . . . . . . . :      0                              
  Record length . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :      0
```

So I suppose it's not unreasonable to think that ofstream might work...

But the [Opening Printer Files as Binary Stream Files](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=files-opening-printer-as-binary-stream) page of the Programmer's guide doesn't mention ofstream and instead just says:

> To open an IBM® i printer file as a binary stream file for
> record-at-a-time processing, use the fopen() function with one of the
> following modes: wb ab
> ***Note: The only way to create a printer file is***
> ***to use the CRTPRTF command. If you use the fopen() function and the***
> ***printer file does not exist, a physical database file is created.***
>
> The valid keyword parameters are: type lrecl indicators recfm

Comment: That's where I started as well.  I similarly found that the Programmer's Guide does not state one way or the other about whether fstream classes work with database files, and they do.  I found I had to use an IFS-style path to the member to open the file.  Then I was able to write to the file using the put-to operator.  So it seems odd, given that stdio.h and recio.h libraries work with both file types, that fstream would only work for database files.

Comment: @ChrisCharlton What error message(s) to you get when the open fails?

Comment: @ChrisCharlton playing around with the IFS, I notice that unlike DB files where the object is surfaced as a member, `/QSYS.LIB/MYLIB.LIB/MYTABLE.FILE/MYTABLE.MBR`.  For a PRTF, the object is the actual file `/QSYS.LIB/MYLIB.LIB/MYPRTF.FILE`.  Makes sense I suppose since there is no actual data storage associated with a PRTF.